# CSV parser in JAVA, double quotes in string (SuperCSV, OpenCSV)

Tags: java, parsing, csv, quotes, supercsv

all day I've been searching how to resolve this probem and nothing...
I want to write function, which convert CSV file to collection of lists (of strings).
Here is this function:

```
public Collection<? extends List<String>> parse() throws IOException {
    Collection<List<String>> collectionOfLists = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    CsvListReader parser = new CsvListReader(Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), CsvPreference.EXCEL_PREFERENCE);

    List<String> row;
    while( (row = parser.read()) != null)
        collectionOfLists.add(row);

    return collectionOfLists;
}

public static String toString(Collection<? extends List<String>> csv) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(List<String> l : csv) {
        for(String s : l)
            builder.append(s).append(',');
        if(builder.length() > 0)
            builder.setCharAt(builder.length()-1,'\n');
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

But e.g. for that input:

```
id, name, city, age
1,"Bob",London,12
```

Output for toString(parse()) is:

```
id, name, city, age
1,Bob,London,12
```

instead of the same like input:/ What can I do, that strings contain \" (quotes) ?
Please help me.

Comment: errr... if you want to write your own, why the "SuperCSV, OpenCSV" in the question title?

Comment: Seems like the library strips the `""`.

Comment: because I was trying use these classes, but I didn't find any solution

Comment: The [javadoc](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/io/CsvListReader.html) probably has what you want.

Comment: I looked through it some times...

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your question whether you're asking....

**1. My data contains quotes - why are they being stripped out?**

In this case, I'd point you to the [CSV specification](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/csv_specification.html) as your CSV file is not properly escaped, so those quotes aren't actually part of your data.

It should be

`1,""Bob"",London,12`

not

`1,"Bob",London,12`

**2. How do I apply quotes when writing (even if the data doesn't contain commas, quotes,  etc)?**

By default Super CSV only escapes if necessary (the field contains a comma, double quote or newline).

If you really want to enable quotes, then you can configure Super CSV with a [quote mode](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/preferences.html#Custom_quote_mode).

For example, you could always quote the name column in your example with the following preferences:

```
private static final CsvPreference ALWAYS_QUOTE_NAME_COL = 
    new CsvPreference.Builder(CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE)
    .useQuoteMode(new ColumnQuoteMode(2)).build();
```

Alternatively, if you want to quote everything then you can use `AlwaysQuoteMode`, or if you want a completely custom solution, then you can write your own `QuoteMode`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And is there any solution such that parser leaves quotes there they was, and prints strings without quotes if they wasn't in input? 


In sense e.g. 

`,, --> ,null, (or ,,), "Bob" --> "Bob", Bob --> Bob and "" --> ""`

Is this possible with the help of SuperCSV or OpenCSV?

Comment: There's a `getUntokenizedRow()` method on the readers, but that's not really what you want. I doubt many libraries will transform from CSV to Java to CSV again with identical input/output (the data will be the same, but the containing structure may differ).

Answer (score 1):

In the `CsvPreference.EXCEL_PREFERENCE` you've given, the quote character is the `"` as described in the [javadoc](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/prefs/CsvPreference.html). The quote character is a character you use to wrap special characters that want you want to appear literally.

As such, for these preferences, the appropriate way to produce your CSV content would be

```
id, name, city, age
1,"""Bob""",London,12
```

Otherwise, the CSV parser simply thinks

```
"Bob"
```

means, literally,

```
Bob
```

since there is no other special character between the quotes. But a quote is a special character so if it appears between quotes, it will be considered, literally, as a quote.

Alternatively, provide a different `CsvPreference` object which has a different quote character.

Make this decision only after you are certain about what your CSV producer is sending you.

Comment: Ok, I know. I mean how to convert CSV file to collection of list such that keep quotes. If you provide a different CsvPreference e.g.

    new CsvPreference.Builder('\'', ',', "\n").build()

than, it doesn't work:

    id,text
    1,"It doesn't work, man"

Comment: @user3521479 The javadoc shows how to do that. [sendon1982](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23001275/438154) provides an example as well.

Answer (score 1):

You create your own Preference.

```
CsvPreference excelPreference = new CsvPreference.Builder('\'', ',', "\n").build();
CsvListReader parser = new CsvListReader(Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile , StandardCharsets.UTF_8), excelPreference);
```

After that, it will output as expected.
In this example, you will strip the single quote if you have that in your csv file and keep the double quote untouched.