# Ignore double quote in the fields when parsing a CSV file using CSV parser

Tags: java, csv, opencsv, apache-commons-csv

Sample Data -

Header1,  full_name,     header3, header4

1. 20, "bob, XXX",    "test",  30
2. 20, "evan"s,YYY ", "test",  30
3. 20, "Tom, ZZZ",    "test",  30

   ```
   CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader, ',', '"');
   ```

The second row doesn't read as expected. since there is a double quote in the full_name column value.

I want to ignore such cases. any suggestion would be appreciated.

using openCSV java api for parsing.

Edit:

I am getting the data from database. one of the database column field has that one double quote in it's value. Because of that the csv data looks malformed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSV parser in JAVA, double quotes in string (SuperCSV, OpenCSV)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000676/csv-parser-in-java-double-quotes-in-string-supercsv-opencsv)

Comment: The CSV is malformed. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180, Rule 7. If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote.

Comment: It is not malformed, the Original data has double quote inside it. @Guenther

Comment: Maybe Java Parser with regex can help you

Comment: I need to rewrite the logic to parse the csv file. I intended to use any csv reader frameworks for now. If nothing works out I might write custom parsing for it. Thanks for suggestion @pilkington

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) can handle unescaped quotes and is also 4x faster than opencsv. Try this code:

```
public static void main(String... args){
    String input = "" +
            "20, \"bob, XXX\", \"test\", 30\n" +
            "20, \"evan\"s,YYY \", \"test\", 30\n" +
            "20, \"Tom, ZZZ\", \"test\", 30 ";


    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();

    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
    List<String[]> rows = parser.parseAll(new StringReader(input));

    //printing values enclosed in [ ]  to make sure you are getting the expected result
    for(String[] row : rows){
        for(String value : row){
            System.out.print("[" + value + "],");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This will produce:

```
[20],[bob, XXX],[test],[30],
[20],["evan"s],[YYY "],[test],[30],
[20],[Tom, ZZZ],[test],[30],
```

Additionally, you can control how to handle unescaped quotes with one of:

```
settings.setUnescapedQuoteHandling(UnescapedQuoteHandling.STOP_AT_DELIMITER);
settings.setUnescapedQuoteHandling(UnescapedQuoteHandling.STOP_AT_CLOSING_QUOTE);
settings.setUnescapedQuoteHandling(UnescapedQuoteHandling.RAISE_ERROR);
settings.setUnescapedQuoteHandling(UnescapedQuoteHandling.SKIP_VALUE);
```

When reading large files, you can use a `RowProcessor` or iterate over each row like this:

```
parser.beginParsing(new File("/path/to/your.csv"));

String[] row;
while ((row = parser.parseNext()) != null) {
    // process row
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this libary. It's open source and free (Apache 2.0 license)

Comment: your solution is works good for small data. I am dealing with huge thousands of rows and hundred's of columns. doing this might add more time. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: There are many ways to read the data. I just posted an example. You can read files with trillions of rows and hundreds of gigabytes with it. Read the tutorial to learn more.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you can use the library to process large files. A 100mb file  with 3 million rows takes about 700ms to be fully parsed on my macbook pro. Hope this helps